# What's the meaning of "take it any further"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbs

I can't understand the meaning of "take that thought any further" in the sentence:

> **A:** You can't stay in a hostel. They're for backpackers and drunks.
>
> **B:** Yeah. Maybe don't take that thought any further.

Comment: Possibly "think further (some more) about hostels and realise that you are a backpacker or drunk"?

Answer (score 1):

> Don't take that thought any further.

means

> Stop thinking about it.

If you take something further, [you develop it](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-something-further), [you advance it to a higher level or more serious degree](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+further).